# Stacking and Ensembling methods in Data Science

Tags: predictive-models, ensemble-learning, stacking

Recently it seems that stacking and ensembling methods have become more popular, and using these methods can give better results than using a single algorithm.

My question is: What are the reasons, statistical or otherwise, behind the improvement in results?

I also understand that at a high level that combining these methods will combine the predictions from different algorithms. Each algorithm has its own strengths and weaknesses, but not sure how combining them will actually improve the results.

Here is a simple balanced example (50% of the labels are actually T and 50% are actually F), where I think stacking or ensembling algorithms will still give the same result as the original model. In this case, for the ties (1 F and 1 T), I decided to select T. The same problem would occur if I selected F instead. This is a little more complicated if I used the predict_proba, but think the same problem would occur.

[image]

Comment: One aspect of ensemble method does is to reduce variance though boosting type algorithm can improve bias at the same time.

Comment: Any ideas on how this improvement occurs? What is the mechanism for the improvement?

Comment: I wrote the following article : https://www.thekerneltrip.com/python/why-does-stacking-works/ presenting hypothesis about why stacking is better, thought it may be useful here.
And apparently, the first suggestion of using "stacking" goes back to... 92 !